# Django Send_Mail Authentication Failure

Tags: python, django, unix, dovecot, roundcube

I am using my mail server to send mail using Django. When I try to use the `send_mail` function, I am met with an authentication error. I know that it is not the password, because I can use it to login to my mail account.

**How My Mail Server is Setup**

I am running Ubuntu 16.0.4 with Nginx and Gunicorn for my Django application. I have installed Roundcube, postfix and dovecot.

**How Do I add Users to Roundcube?**

For me, the only way I know how to do this is by just adding a new user from the CLI using `adduser <user>` and from there, logging into Roundcube so that my new user is added to the Roundcube database, and I have an accessible account on Roundcube.

**What I Suspect to be The Issue**

Since I am creating the users for Roundcube directly from the CLI and they are full Unix users, I can only login to Roundcube using their actual username, and not `username@domain.tld`. I **suspect** that Django is trying to authenticate with `user@domain.tld` rather than `user` and that is what is causing the issue.

**How Can I Fix This?**

I am not sure, hence why I am here. I have done my research and cannot find the proper information on making it so that I can login to Roundcube using `user@domain.tld` instead of just `user`, but I don't think this will solve my issue.

I have also done research and cannot find an answer on how to create just a mail user, and not a full-blown Unix user. I was thinking this might be my best option. Although, I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Why do you suspect that Django is trying to authenticate with `user@domain.tld`? What are you using for `EMAIL_HOST_USER`? Have you tried `EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user'` instead of `EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@dimain.tld'`

Comment: @Alasdair , silly enough, i have not tried that. It is because I am using user@domain.tld because I thought I needed it. Let me try user by itself

Comment: @Alasdair so I changed my EMAIL_HOST_USER to just user and it worked. I feel silly, yet happy that I learned something new! Thanks :)